# Add contact form to iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, sendmail

I would like to add a contact form to my app for user inquiries and suggestions. I can send a mail with below code but would be nice if 'to' field wasn't editable or better mail view controller isn't shown.

```
  MFMailComposeViewController *mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
  mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
  [mc setSubject:emailTitle];
  [mc setMessageBody:messageBody
              isHTML:YES];
  [mc setToRecipients:recipents];
  [self presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Can I implement such a contact form in iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change the Mail form - not though public API.

If you want a custom form then you would need a custom way of communicaion. You could implement a web service on your server that receives the messages.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Hermann is correct - you can't change mail form.

Moreover, I found that once I put in the “contact us” email link, I would indeed get emails from users, but majority of them are blank emails. Then I realized - users wanted to quit the email interface but tapped Cancel by mistake. They don’t like to send emails to strangers.

[AppyForm](http://www.appyform.com) does exactly what the accepted answer suggests - a custom form with backend service, so that you can collect feedback without hosting your own web service.

p.s. I built AppyForm, because I couldn't find another service like it.